# C# Pre-invkoing delegates to improve performance

Tags: c#, performance, lambda, delegates, invoke

I am doing some dynamic deleagate invocation in c#.

Since my deleagates mainly instantiate objects, I wanted to compare their performance.

Since I cannot post my full code (the project is way too large) this is what most of my collections/variables contain:

- objCreatorrs - `Dictionary<ushort, Func<int, Result>>`- holds lambdas by an id. The lambdas look like so `id => new SomeObjectType() {Id = id}`
- propSetters - `Dictionary<int, Action<Selection>>` - holds actions by id.They look like this `someObject => AStaticClass.SomeMethod(someobject)`
- inputSelections - is just an array of `Selection` objects that holds 2 integers. Nothing special

So I did a test the roughly represent the following

```
for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                foreach (var selection in inputSelections)
                {
                    var s = objCreators[selection.MarketID].Invoke(selection.SelectionID + c);
                    propSetters[selection.SelectionID].Invoke(s);
                }
            }
        }
```

I compared to it to some if/else code and got the following results

```
# 1 - Static If/Else: 209ms. | Static Switch 201ms. | Dynamic: 794ms.
# 2 - Static If/Else: 213ms. | Static Switch 188ms. | Dynamic: 201ms.
# 3 - Static If/Else: 195ms. | Static Switch 187ms. | Dynamic: 188ms.
# 4 - Static If/Else: 193ms. | Static Switch 186ms. | Dynamic: 187ms.
# 5 - Static If/Else: 199ms. | Static Switch 193ms. | Dynamic: 186ms.
# 6 - Static If/Else: 196ms. | Static Switch 186ms. | Dynamic: 193ms.
# 7 - Static If/Else: 196ms. | Static Switch 187ms. | Dynamic: 186ms.
# 8 - Static If/Else: 194ms. | Static Switch 188ms. | Dynamic: 187ms.
# 9 - Static If/Else: 193ms. | Static Switch 186ms. | Dynamic: 188ms.
# 10 - Static If/Else: 193ms. | Static Switch 186ms. | Dynamic: 186ms.
```

As you can see in #1, the first time I invoke my deleagates It takes me 794ms, and in the next tests it drops down to around 190ms.

So I decided to improve my performance, by iterating through all my deleagtes and invoking them with a dummy paramter before running the tests, like so:

```
 foreach (var @delegate in objCreators)
        {
            var s = objCreators[@delegate.Key].Invoke(@delegate.Key);
            propSetters[@delegate.Key].Invoke(s);
        }
```

However, my test results did not change.

My question is **what gets cached/compiled the first time I run my 10 tests**, that I can't reporoduce by simply iterating over all my lambdas and invoking them with a dummy paramter before running my tests.

*I thought it was the parameter, but I then made my lambda invokactions depend on the value of c, and I still managed to get improved performance after the first run, so its not that.*

Comment: I don't believe the JIT compiler exclusively operates at the function level. It is probable that if your delegates are run with a dummy parameter then most of the code inside them is not JIT compiled until it is actually required.

Comment: This makes sense. However, I am exclusively calling .Compile () on my func/action delegates when I add them into the dictionaries

Comment: Furthermore, if this is the case,  my inital invoke, before running the test, should force the JIT compiler to compile them. I doubt the compilation result is discarded after leaving the scope. Also, my dummy parameter is 0. As far as the compiler is concerned - its a normal and valid parameter. And, as I mentioned in my post - i tried invoking them with parameters, identical to the ones in the test - still got no improvement